How do I import 3D footprints into Altium CircuitMaker?
I need to create my own part, so therefore I need to import a pre-made footprint and 3D-model.
I have the model in .step, .wrl, .iges etc...
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32mp151a.html#cad-resources
How can that be done in Altium CircuitMaker?

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-circuitmaker/pcb-3d-body
